# A4 Insecure Direct Object References in C - how to fix fopen?

Tags: c, fopen, fortify

here I have the fortify's report for an A4 vulnerability especialy for fopen usage.

/* START */

Source: file_main.c:71 main(1)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ ...
```

Sink: file.c:689 fopen()

```
/* Open a store file */
if ((fp= fopen(cpInputFile, "r")) == NULL)
{ ...
```

/* END */

Abstract:
*Attackers are able to control the file system path argument to fopen() at file.c
line 689, which allows them to access or modify otherwise protected files.*

I know that it could be fixed with a White List, but if anyone knows other way to fix it may be with other function or other, please help me.

gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)

thanks so much!

Comment: What's the path that cpInputFile takes? Where is it derived from? What is the file you open used for?

Comment: basically ,the source of cpInputFile is in the main argv, as the fortify show us. so  that means that the user could be a put anything string .

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking .. are you asking how to protect access to the `cpInputFile` file path?

Comment: sorry if I didnt let undersand ...My asking is about how to fix the fortify vulnerability.

Comment: If the program is supposed to read a file that is freely specified by the user, then that's simply what it does.  Probably, then, the Fortify vulnerability should be documented (if even that), but otherwise ignored.  That presents a *bona fide* issue only if the program operates with different privileges than its user's, such as if it is SUID.

Comment: Even without knowing that tool or your code, the message seems pretty clear to me. If not for you, reading the fine manual should help. If not, ask the vendor